# Amazon EC2 Capacity & Workflow Questions

Tags: windows, hosting, amazon-ec2, virtualization

I’m hoping some of you with experience using amazon EC2 could offer some advice… of course it’ll be subjective which is fine, I’m pretty sure your guestimate would be better than mine.

I am planning on moving all my client’s websites from shared hosting environments to Amazon EC2.  They’re all pretty low traffic sites (the busiest site receives around 50 unique visitors a day).  There’s about 8 sites, but I may expand this as I take on more projects and host more sites… current capacity planning is for say 12 sites.

Each site runs on ASP.Net (Umbraco CMS), and requires a SQL Server database.

My thoughts are one of the following:

1. Setup a Small Instance (1.7gb RAM, 1 EC2 Compute Unit), and run IIS and SQL Server Express on that server.
2. Setup 2 Micro Instances (613MB Ram each, Up to 2 EC2 Compute Units) – one for IIS, the other for SQL Server.

Which arrangement do you think would work the best for my requirements.  I’ve started setting up a Micro instance with Server 2008, SQL Server Express, etc… and finding it not coping with the memory requirements, hence considering expanding.  I could always configure on a Small instance, then export the AMI and fire it up in a Micro instance after, and do the same every time any serious changes to the server are required.  I guess I could even do all updates etc on a spare Small Spot instance, then switch load that AMI up in a Micro and transfer the IP Address across, so I don’t need to do too much work on the production servers. I figure if I store all my website data files on EBS Volumes, then it should be fairly easy to move hosting between servers with minimal downtime, while never working on a production server.

I’m interested to know what you all think, and what strategies you employ for such activities as upgrades, windows updates, software installations, etc.

And what capacity do you think I’d need for my requirements.

Cheers
Greg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first-up, Server 2008 doesn't play well in the 613MB RAM the Micro instance gives you. It runs, but it's a dog, and it barks louder the more services (IIS, SSE, etc) you layer on top. We using nothing smaller than a Small for Server 2008, and in fact typically do the environment config in a Medium and scale down to Small once the heavy lifting is complete and the OS is ready to use. Server 2003, however, seems to breathe easier on a Micro - but we still do the config on a larger instance and scale down.

We're running low-traffic websites on Server 2003/IIS6 in a Micro, with a Server 2008/SS install on a shared, separate, Small instance. We do also have one Server 2008/IIS7 Micro build running, but only to remind ourselves why we don't use it more widely. ;)

Larger websites run Server 2008/IIS7 in either Small or Medium instances, but almost always still using that shared separate SS instance for database services. We try not to deploy multiple SS installations, since it makes maintenance and backups more complex.

Stashing content and config on EBS Volumes is of course good practice, unless you like rebuilding the entire system whenever an Instance disappears. Snapshotting your Instances periodically is also good practice, since you can spin-up a new Instance from a baseline AMI and swap the snapshot in as a boot Volume for fast recovery in the event of disaster.

Comment: Great info Jonners, thanks for that. So do you think a small instance running IIS and SS would be enough for a dozen sites?  If i need 2 small instances, its probably going to be too expensive unfortunately :(

Comment: something i dont completely understand about snapshots... If i have an instance running off an EBS as its root drive, and i take a snapshot of that, then i fire up a new instance using an AMI, how do i sawp the snapshot in as boot volume?  Oh, and does the snapshot take up the full size of the EBS drive (so if its a 30gb ebs drive, and i take a snapshot, do i then get charged for 60gb of EBS storage?)

Comment: A Small instance will run Server 2003+IIS6+SSE happily until traffic workload ramps up - then you'll need to upscale. It'll run Server 2008+IIS7+SSE as well, but the upscale point will hit you sooner because the configuration demands more resources.

Comment: Given an EBS-backed Instance (i.e. the AMI is an EBS-backed rather than S3-backed image) you can stop the VM, identify the Volume it is using, and snapshot it. You can then restart your Instance and carry on. Later, either by design or misfortune, the Instance dies - you now spin-up a new Instance, stop it, detach the Volume, create a new Volume from your snapshot taken before, attach it back to the stopped Instance as /dev/sda1, and restart it. Our estate-management tool automates this, but we did it by hand through the console before it existed.

Comment: Re. Snapshot storage consumption - they are deltas from the previous snapshot. From http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/ ... "Amazon EBS provides the ability to back up point-in-time snapshots of your data to Amazon S3 for durable recovery. Amazon EBS snapshots are incremental backups, meaning that only the blocks on the device that have changed since your last snapshot will be saved. If you have a device with 100 GBs of data, but only 5 GBs of data has changed since your last snapshot, only the 5 additional GBs of snapshot data will be stored back to Amazon S3".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about EBS Storage.. the console reports it as the full size of the volume, so i wasn't sure.  makes sense that its just an incremental back up though.. would be nice if it'd report the actual size..

Comment: Re: Firing up VMs from snapshots.. given the procedure is to fire up an isntance, stop it, then start it up again after you've attached the new volume, is there a need for an AMI at all?  Seems you'll be replacing the drive built by the AMI using your EBS volume anyway, so why pay for storage of an AMI as well as the Volume?  Or am i missing something?

Comment: Re: Capacity.. what do you think would be better:  1 small instance for both IIS and SS, or 2 Micro instances (one for IIS, the other for SS)?

Comment: You need at least one AMI as a VM template image - you can't start a VM directly from an EBS volume, it's the AMI that instantiates a volume at boot time. Of course, there's no reason why the AMI has to be yours - if you want, you can use one of the Amazon pre-configured Windows AMIs as the baseline, in which case you're not paying to store an AMI of your own.

Comment: I'd go with Small instances - I wouldn't advocate running Windows, IIS and SS all on a Micro. We tend to use Micros for Server 2003 and IIS (or Apache) and low-throughput tasks. But then, the joy of EC2 is you can suck it and see - try a Micro, and if it drags it's heels just snapshot the config, scrap the VM, and bring a Small up with its' boot volume switched to a volume created from your snapshot.

Comment: Update: Amazon have at last released Server 2008 R2, which is a 64-bit instance type. You can't run Small or Medium instances from it (these seem to be locked to 32-bits) but interestingly the Micro size *does* support x64, so you can run 2008 R2 - and it performs *much* better than R1 in that configuration. Still tight on memory, but usable.

Comment: Worth mentioning - this has gotten even easier. If all volumes are EBS volumes, you can just clone the Volumes of a failed Instance and spin a new one up off of the clones. No data loss, no crazy swapping routine - I was impressed at how few CLICKS I had to perform to get a replacement Instance up!